# Stats question bionomial distribution.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics

It is known that $47$% of students at a large university are male. If we take a random sample of $200$ students at the university, what is the approximate probability that less than half of them are male?

Can anyone help me with this question? I am doing a review for my finals and I am stuck solving this question.

Comment: You are expected to use a normal approximation. I do not know whether you are expected to make a continuity correction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hints/Beginning of problem**

Note the keyword: "*at a* **large** *university*"

We may assume then that the number of students at the university is much larger than $200$, so much so to the point that the question of taking 200 students at the university without replacement can be well approximated by the question of taking 200 students at the university *with replacement* (*since the probability of having selected a person more than once is assumed to be minuscule due to the size of the university*).

In other words, we may treat this as a binomial distribution with $n=200$ and $p=0.47$

What is the average number of men you would expect in two hundred draws with replacement?

> $\mu = np = 200\cdot 0.47 = 94$.  Note: This formula is applicable for binomially distributed random variables, this is not the general formula for expected value in most other cases.

What is the standard deviation on the number of men you would expect in two hundred draws with replacement?

> $\sigma = \sqrt{np(1-p)} = \sqrt{200\cdot 0.47\cdot 0.53} = \sqrt{49.82}\approx 7.06$.  Note: This formula is applicable for binomially distributed random variables, this is not the general formula for standard deviation in most other cases.

Less than half of the people selected being men corresponds to the number of men being one of $0,1,2,\dots,98,99$.  Using a normal approximation to the binomial, we want to find the area of the graph to the left of $99.5$ (*the area to the left of $0$ is insignificant and will not affect our approximation*)

How many standard deviations above the mean is $99.5$?

> Left as exercise to reader

What then is the probability approximated by in terms of the standard normal distribution?  Looking that up on a table, how much is that?

> Left as exercise to reader

Comment: Nice use of spoilers!

Comment: Thanks it was a great explanation.

Comment: @Saad glad I could help.  As for why we look to $99.5$ instead of $99$, that arises because if we were looking at the histogram (*bar graph*) for a binomial distribution (the binomial random variable being number of men), the rectangles are centered on the integers, so the bar corresponding to $99$ men appears on the graph between $98.5$ and $99.5$.  Adding up the areas of the rectangles compared to finding the area under the curve of the normal approximation, if we don't correct it we can miss out on the area from $90$ to $90.5$.  Although not noticable here, with smaller $\sigma$ it will be.